# Локализация строковых констант в Zend Framework

Tags: framework, php, zend-framework

Есть проект на ZF, в котором строковые константы разбросаны по всему коду. Требуется провести рефакторинг, реализовать простой и удобный механизм локализации их в одном месте (БД либо отдельный PHP класс), есть перспектива использования нескольких языков. Как это правильно делается? Где можно посмотреть?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ZF есть ["родной" механизм интернационализации](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.introduction.html). Прмеры использования: [1](http://devzone.zend.com/1441/zend-framework-and-translation/) и [2](http://web-blog.org.ua/articles/zend-framework-localizatsiya-proektov-chast-vtoraya) . Этот механизм по сути дела является обёрткой над разными методами локализации (xml, gettext, php массивы и др.).